# Stream on snowpark

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to subscribe to a kafka topic and ingest/ transform the data in snowflake.I would like to use the [snowpark api for scala](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/scala/com/snowflake/snowpark/index.html) and the [Streams & Tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-examples.html#basic-example) available in snowflake.

I couldnt find anything in the API Dokumentation nor via google. Is this option already available and if not is it planed on some roadmap?

Comment: While this is technically possible, it's not available or documented way as of now. For now, our documented way is to use our [Kafka connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector.html) to subscribe to a topic and ingest the data in Snowflake.

Comment: Thank you for your responde. I'm aware of the [Kafka connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector.html) as a perfect tool to load data into a snowflake table. I'm looking for a solution to transform the small portion of data that were appended by the kafka connector. 
If I would use ordanary transformation and df I would always tranform the whole table/df

Comment: Like I said I know this should be possible technically, it's just not something we we do as of now. That doesn't means you can't try it from your side. I would say try something and if you get issues along post the scripts and errors and we'll try to help you.